# How to save data with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have many-to-many relationship between Game and Account models like below:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :games, :through => :account_games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :accounts, :through => :account_games
end

class AccountGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Now I know let's say I want to create a record something like:

```
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
@account.games << Game.first
@account.save
```

But how am I supposed to update some of the attributes in AccountGame while I'm doing that? Lets say that `AccountGame` has some field called `score`, how would I update this attribute? Can you tell me about the best way to do that? To add any field in the through table while I'm saving the object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
@accountgame = @account.account_games.build(:game => Game.first, :score => 100)
@accountgame.save
```

Though I'd strongly recommend that if you start adding columns to your join-model that you call it something different eg "subscription" or "membership" or something similar. Once you add columns it stops being a join model and starts just being a regular model.

Comment: You would add the score with the game, not sure it's clear: `@account.account_games.build(:game => Game.first, :score => 100)`

Comment: yes, thanks, sorry silly me I forgot to actually add that bit.

Comment: What Robin mentions is a work-around, but does not answer the OPs original question. *How to do you update some of the attributes in the join-model during "Account.account_games.create()"*

Comment: Yes, good point. You could do this by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` there are lots of questions on S/O about the use of this, stick it in the searchbar and have a looksee :)

Comment: I agree with @Taryn East, renaming the join table is necessary.  Using the Rails join table conventional naming used for many_to_many associations can cause issues when using has_many through

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
class AccountGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :game
  attr_accessible :account_id, :game_id    #<======= Notice this line
end
```