# Temporarily creating and associating models before save [Rails, Ajax, Google Maps]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a trip planner application using rails 4, coffeescript, the Google Maps API, and jquery. On our trip planner page, we let users link multiple destinations together on a Google map, and save the trip to their account if they want.

We have 3 main models we are working with:

**Trips** - contains the name of the trip, start and end dates

**Destinations** - locations on the map, identified by a name and geo coordinates (lat/long). Destinations are not directly linked to a trip.

**DestinationOrders** - this is the table contains the order of destinations in a trip (like a linked list). The columns are trip_id, destination_id, and order_authority. Order_authority will be a number we use to sort the order of destinations using the [method described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205/linked-list-in-sql)

A typical set of actions on the page are:

1. Load the google map
2. Select the first destination using Google's places autocomplete functionality   (javascript). Add a marker to the Google Map for the first destination
3. Add a second destination, place the marker, link the two destinations with a path
4. Add a third destination, place the marker, link destinations 2 and destination 3 with a path
5. User clicks 'Save' to store the trip in his account

We are fairly new to rails and I'm wondering the best way to approach this given the back and forth between javascript, the controller, and the model. We don't want to associate the trip to his account until he click save.

Possible approaches we've thought of:
Do we create new instances of the models, then when the user clicks save, save all of the instances to the database? The problem here is when trying to create the `DestinationOrder`, as it requires a trip id and a destination id which have not been created yet. Using our steps above, this would be something like:

1. `trip = Trip.new`
2. Send location information (place) to controller via Ajax, then:

`firstDestination = Destination.new (name: place.name, lat: place.geometry.location.lat, long: place.geometry.location.long)`

`firstDestOrder = DestinationOrder.new`

Another possible (naive) solution would be to keep everything stored in javascript variables until the user clicks save, then send an ajax request with all of the destinations in order and create the models.

Finally, we thought of the possibility of creating and saving trips and destinations as the user goes along. That is, when a user first gets to the page, a trip would be created and saved. When the user adds a destination, that destination would be saved as well. This allows us to pass `DestinationOrder` those id, and if the user clicks save, we would associate the `trip_id` with his account. However, if the user left the site mid-creation, this would create a zombie trip with no associated user, and would require some process to clean these up every-so-often.

What is the most efficient way to approach a situation like this? I hope my explanation makes sense - please let me know if I need to clarify. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your schema is a bit weird. Seems like what you really want to do is create Trips that are associated with destinations and each one of those destinations has and order. What you are really looking for is a has  many through associations, this will give you the flexibility of adding the order attribute on the join table.

A Trip has many Destinations through DestinationOrder, that way DestinationOrder serves as the glue (join model) between the Destination Model ad the Trip model. It seems like that is what you are trying to do but you never quite said the name of the association so I thought i'd clarify that.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Now to the order of operation.
As the user creates a trip, I would save that trip.
Once that trip is created you can start adding destinations to it. 
Yes tou could potentially create trips without destinations but that gives the user the ability to come back and keep filling out the trip. Trips are something that take a long time to plan, so I thin it is fine to create the trip even if it does not have any destinations and then add destinations as they are created.

See this for reference [How to save data with has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404859/how-to-save-data-with-has-many-through)

Hope that helps some.